# How can I make side panels without margin-top hacks?

Tags: html, css

The concept of `float` and `display: inline-block` is sort of hard to understand when making side panels.

In a perfect world, I'd like my this blue print to be the design of my site:
[image]

I achieved the design; but noticed when I tried to add new stuff, I kept band-aiding my horrible hacks with more CSS hacks creating a mess (using a ton of margin-left, right, top, and bottom) - and in the end it wastes my development time since some hacks didn't work on all browsers.

Anyways, trying to avoid margin-top/bottom hacks, this is my attempt at making side panels:

https://jsfiddle.net/p367aL8w/1/

My thought process in this example was to give each panel a `display inline-block;` property, while pushing them all the way to the right so they can go to the side. This isn't working though. What's the proper way to do this? (I would really prefer not to use flex box).

Comment: do you want to use bootstrap ?

Comment: @MinarMnr I'd prefer not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I prefer a simple modification in DOM and that will fix all the issues with out any browser specific css hacks. Just add a container for three side panel widgets and align that container to right. Please see the sample below

```css
#mainpanel{
  height: 500px;
  width: 65%;
  background-color: #aaa;
  float: left;
}

#sidepanel{
  width: 30%;
  background-color: white;
  float: right;
}

.sidepanel01, .sidepanel02, .sidepanel03{
  width:100%;
  height:100px;
  float:left;
  background: #aaa;
  margin-bottom: 20px
}
```

```html
<div id="mainpanel">
Main panel
</div>
<div id="sidepanel">
   <div class="sidepanel01">
     Panel1
   </div>

   <div class="sidepanel02">
     Panel2
   </div>

   <div class="sidepanel03">
    Panel3
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: amazing - just what I was looking for

Answer (score 0):

I really like the simplicity of `flex` based design and avoid `float` at all costs except for simple inline flowing of elements, such as positioning a text around an image.

Please see the `flex` solution below. CSS `grids` also provide a good solution.

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.wrapper .main-panel {
  flex: 1 1 auto; /* shorthand for flex-grow flex-shrink flex-basis */
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  border: 2px solid red;
}

.wrapper .side-panel {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  width: 200px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.wrapper .side-panel > div {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  border: 2px solid red;  
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="main-panel">Main panel</div>
  <div class="side-panel">
    <div class="side-panel-item">Panel 1</div>
    <div class="side-panel-item">Panel 2</div>
    <div class="side-panel-item">Panel 3</div>
  </div>
</div>
```